# How to make the text send back of the red object rectangle?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

There are two objects.

1. Red rectangle - which is like the background of the text and not movable.
2. Text - which is movable.

I want the text to send backwards of the object 1 because I'm planning to reduce the object 1 opacity so the object 2 can be seen even though it's in the back of the object 1.

Check the image below :

[image: Sample Image]

This is my sample code but its not working as expected

```
canvas.bringToFront(object1);
canvas.sendToBack(object2);
```

Comment: Are you calling `canvas.renderAll()` after that?

Comment: Yes I call canvas.renderAll() at the end. @Durga

Comment: Can you make a snippet stating the issue?